# Бот не находит участников с определенной ролью хотя они есть

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Необходимо получить список участников с определенной ролью. Для этого использовал `role.members`, но в этом списке не было ни одного участника, хотя в дискорде участников с ролью `role`было штук 20. Помогите объясните, ну тупой я извините
Вот код:

```py
@bot.command(pass_content=True, aliases=["clanwar"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=False)
async def __clanwar(ctx, clan1: discord.Role = None, clan2: discord.Role = None):
    if (clan1 == None):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Вы не указали первый клан", description="@упомяните роль первого клана", color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    elif (clan2 == None):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Вы не указали второй клан", description="@упомяните роль второго клана", color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    else:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Война назревает!", color = discord.Color.dark_blue())
        clan2users = clan2.members
        #print(clan2users) выводит None, хотя в дискорде участников с этой ролью около 20
        #подскажите почему так происходит
```

Главный вопрос: почему в списке юзеров с ролью пусто, хотя они есть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=`Айди роли`)

role.members - `вывод объектов пользователей с указанной ролью в виде списка`